# How to fix "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Transform.call')" for ethereumjs-tx

Tags: react-native, private-key, sign, smartcontracts

I am want to develop a mobile application which will send a transaction to interact with my smart contract.

When execute "ethereumjs-tx.sign(..)" , it throw exception.
(FYR: I am using web3@0.19, ethereumjs-util@4.4 and ethereumjs-tx@1.3 include my app.)

I tried to execute other function in ethereumjs-tx, such as toCreationAddress() and getChainId(). They are work.
Also, I tried the latest version of web3, ethereumjs-tx and ethereumjs-util, but not helpful.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

import './global';

var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/'));
var util = require('ethereumjs-util');
var tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');

export default function App() {

  pressMe = () => {
    var rawTx = {
        nonce: '0x002D',
        gasPrice: '0x3B9ACA00',
        gasLimit: '0xC20A',
        to: <<..smart contract address..>>
        value: '0x00',
        data: '0x...',
        chainId:"0x03"
    }
    console.log(rawTx);
    var p = new Buffer(<<..privateKey..>>, 'hex');
    var transaction = new tx(rawTx);

    transaction.sign(p) ;

  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <Button onPress={this.pressMe} title="Click"></Button>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

When run "pressMe" function, and execute "transaction.sign(p)", it throw exception.

[image: Error capture screen]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that an implementation of `Buffer` isn't provided in RN.
You'll need to add one as a dependency:
`yarn add buffer`

..and then, add to your imports:
`import { Buffer } from 'buffer';`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `Buffer`. It will be embedded in the React-native. Please import the `Buffer`.

```js
var Buffer = require('buffer/').Buffer
var p = Buffer(<<..privateKey..>>, 'hex');
```